# Как запретить скрытие адресной строки браузера на мобильном устройстве при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема заключается в том что на странице есть position: fixed елементы и когда происходит скролл а за ним скрытие адресной строки браузера то елемент немного меняет своё местоположение

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу, выглядит неряшливо при свайпе вниз в мобильном хроме. Объекты имеющие fixed занимают свое место с заметной задержкой при скрытии верхней панели

Comment: В основном, решения сводятся к тому что бы запретить скролл `<html>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953987/14168867

Comment: @Ein ваше решение не работает